# How to remove part of a string

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I keep reading the `sed` documentation and lots of posts but can't seem to figure this out. I have a large number of Java files. In those files are calls to a method that take the enumeration converted to an integer using the `toInt()` method. I want to go through all of the files and get rid of `.toInt()` for a specific enumeration.

This is what I want. The original code strings:

```
foo(ENUM_NAME.ENUM_VALUE.toInt(), arg2, arg3)
foo(ENUM_NAME.ENUM_VALUE2.toInt(), arg2, arg3)
```

I want to end up with:

```
foo(ENUM_NAME.ENUM_VALUE, arg2, arg3)
foo(ENUM_NAME.ENUM_VALUE2, arg2, arg3)
```

`ENUM_VALUE` could be hundreds of different possibilities so I can't hard code. It appears there is some confusion as to what needs to change so I will try to be more clear.

There is an enumeration called `TRANF_FIELD` in my Java files. The values available for that enumeration could be one of a two thousand values, followed by `.toInt()`. I need to get rid of the `.toInt()`. The function names are all irrelevant.

The following are examples of code constructs that are interspersed throughout my Java code and how they should be processed:

> `TRANF_FIELD.TRANF_VALUE_1.toInt()`
>                   I want the `.toInt()` deleted, leaving `TRANF_FIELD.TRANF_VALUE_1` left over.
>   `TRANF_FIELD.TRANF_KILL_ME.toInt()`
>                   I want the `.toInt()` deleted, leaving `TRANF_FIELD.TRANF_KILL_ME`
>   `TRANG_FIELD.TRANG_VALUE_1.toInt()`
>                   No change, because it's not `TRANF_FIELD`.
>   `TRANF_FIELD.TRANF_VALUE_1.length()`
>                   No change, because it's not `.toInt()`.

Comment: Will the format always be `string(string.string.string(), string, string)` and you will always want to get rid just of the `string()`? Can it be `string(string.string(), string)` for example?

Comment: It could be a lot of different things but I know it is not realistic to get everything covered. If I could get something like ENUM_NAME.ENUM_VALUE.toInt() replaced with ENUM_NAME.ENUM_VALUE it would be a good start.

Comment: that's just something like `awk -vFS='[.)]' '{print $1"."$2$4")"}'`

Comment: That works if I only have the enumerations in a file. The problem is that the lines are mixed in with other code so it falls apart.

Comment: I'd need to know how the input looks to know what not to match

Comment: That's the problem. The input is a Java source file so I can't guarantee any formal input. I just know that any place I find any occurrence of a particular enumeration with a .toInt() on the end I want to get rid of the .toInt(). For example TRANF_FIELD.XXXX.toInt() or TRANF_FIELD.XX2.toInt() needs be replaced by TRANF_FIELD.XXX or TRANF_FIELD.XX2

Comment: Umm, if it's always `toInt` why not just `sed 's/\.toInt()[, ]/,/g' file` (or just `sed 's/\.toInt()//g' file`)

Comment: The toInt() is valid for other cases. It is only for something starting with a specific enumeration name and values. The XXXX part is unknown and where I am stuck.

Comment: Is it always `TRANF_FIELD` whose `toInt()` you want to remove, or what's the criteria for what `toInt()` should be removed?

Comment: That is correct. Inside the Java file there will be a large number of references to TRANF_FIELD. In the format of TRANF_FIELD.<somevalue>.toInt() and I want to get rid of the .toInt() in every occurrence.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and clarify what will actually be constant? What is `foo`? Will `foo` always be there? How can we differentiate between `foo(ENUM_NAME.ENUM_VALUE.toInt())` that should be changed and `bar(ENUM_NAME.ENUM_VALUE.toInt())` that shouldn't? Basically how can we know which `toInt` should be removed and which left alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to change all occurrences of

```
TRANF_FIELD.some_enum_value.toInt()
```

to

```
TRANF_FIELD.that_enum_value
```

while leaving other enumerations (e.g., `TRANG_FIELD.TRANG_VALUE.toInt()`)
and other methods (e.g., `TRANF_FIELD.TRANF_VALUE.length()`) alone. 
This seems simple:

```
sed 's/\(TRANF_FIELD\.[A-Za-z0-9_]*\)\.toInt()/\1/'
```

where

- `[A-Za-z0-9_]*` is any number of alphanumeric characters (including underscores). 
  This is intended to match any valid enumeration value. 
  Actually, `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*` would be better,
  because `[A-Za-z0-9_]*` could match an empty string, or one beginning with a digit.
- `\(`…`\)` groups the enumeration name (`TRANF_FIELD`), the literal period (`\.`),
  and the enumeration value (from the first bullet).
- `\1` means “replace the complete string that you found with the first group”,
  i.e., discard the `.toInt()` part.
- To handle multiple occurrences per line, add `g` (global) after the last slash.
- This will not handle embedded whitespace, e.g., `TRANF_FIELD . TRANF_VALUE`. 
  Fixing this is left as an exercise.
- This will not handle expressions that are broken across lines; e.g.,

  ```
      i = TRANF_FIELD
               .TRANF_VALUE.toInt();
  ```

  That’s harder to fix.

Comment: That is what I needed G-Man. I couldn't figure out how to get it to to keep the TRANF_VALUE part. I knew it had something to do with the \1 but I couldn't get it to work. I can handle split lines manually. I just didn't want to hand modify hundreds of files.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your help folks. I added the -i from one answer, including the path to all java files, to what G-man suggested and it works. If you guys are ever on Long Island i'll buy you a beer. That saved me a bunch of time.

```
sed -i 's/\(TRANF_FIELD\.[A-Za-z0-9_]*\)\.toInt()/\1/g'
```

Comment: @Mohsen: Seriously? You rejected my edit because I fixed problems with punctuation and capitalization?

Comment: Oh, sorry, i made a mistake, i think you edit post, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS, an inline (`-i`) `sed` could do this:

`sed -i 's:\.toInt()::' filename`

Where it will just substitute the instance of ".toInt()" with "" - the `.` is escaped so that it does not act as a wild card.

As you mention multiple files, then you will have to loop this command by searching for all files in the current directory and sub directories:

`find . -type f -exec sed -i 's:\.toInt()::' {} \;`

However, this will error if filenames contain spaces, so we can use the `xargs` command to deal with this which will place quotes around all filenames:

`find . -type f | xargs -I{} sed -i 's:\.toInt()::' "{}"`

However, this will also pick compiled files too so to avoid these we can use a useful feature in `perl` to ignore them:

`find . -type f | perl -nle 'print if -T' | xargs -I{} sed -i 's:\.toInt()::' "{}"`

Answer (score -1):

```
sed 's/ENUM_NAME\.\(.*\)\.toInt()/ENUM_NAME.\1/g'
```

Comment: Please expand this answer. One line answers are discouraged, since they often include complex actions that others, including the OP, may not fully understand.